# MPEG-DASH Encoding for Live Streaming

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I want to do encode a live stream for MPEG-DASH in various bitrates and resolutions for live playback.

Everything I found so far either uses only the source resolution (Nimble, nginx-rtmp-module) or seems to be only for VOD streaming(DASHEncoder).

Is it possible to use DASHEncoder with a live input (rtmp stream) and how would I do that?
If not, is it possible to use nginx-rtmp + ffmpeg for what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different services available which support such use-cases, like [NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/scalable-live-video-streaming-nginx-plus-bitmovin/).

I also successfully managed to run a live stream with [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/dash-hls-live-streaming/) and to the best of my knowledge [livestream.com](https://livestream.com/) is also capable of doing that.